# How to get HP ALM 14 Login Authentication Token using REST API with postman

Tags: rest, postman, hp-alm

i am using postman as a rest client to get the login authentication token from HP ALM 14.

**Using API**

```
https://something.com/qcbin/authentication-point/authenticate
```

**Request Body**

i tried both format in request body

XML Format

```
<alm-authentication>
    <user>username</user>
    <password>password</password>
</alm-authentication>
```

JSON Format

```
{
    "username": "username",
    "password": "password"
}
```

the response for the above api is
[image]

in the above image only i got **JSESSIONID** and **BIGipServerMSGRDG01PEX** but in the document and some other tutorial they used four tokens

1.LWSSO_COOKIE_KEY

2.QCSession

3.ALM_USER

4.XSRF-TOKEN

how can i get all these tokens and set in the future api request in postman?

Comment: Isn't that in response body?

Comment: first they got lwsso cookie and set it in the new request header to get all other token

Comment: have you any idea how to get these tokens?

Comment: no, I am sorry :/

Comment: You need an interceptor plugin (if I'm not mistaken) for Postman which captures cookies

Answer (score 0):

Do a post request for this url "https://something.com/qcbin/api/authentication/sign-in"
using basic authentication